# What are the issues when publishing ES2015 npm packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

As most of programmers:

1. I write my source-code in ES2015+ or TypeSCript
2. I transpile my code in ES5
3. I publish the transpiled code as an npm package.

The support of ES2015 is now widely spread. The maintained versions of node.js support ES2015. In the browser land ES2015 [seems also widely spread](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6).

Publishing packages in ES2015 has advantages such as [smaller bundle size](https://philipwalton.com/articles/deploying-es2015-code-in-production-today/#is-this-really-worth-the-extra-effort%3F) and native support for ES2015 features.

**Do you know any issue to publish packages in ES2015?**

**Have you some npm statistics about the proportion of ES2015 published packages?**

## Findings

In the past, packages were [published in ES2015](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/issues/137). This produced some issue on the client side. Bundler users seem to assume that the code published on [*main* and *module* entries](https://github.com/stereobooster/package.json#user-content-package-bundlers) are ES5-compatible. Thus, they [exclude their packages' dependencies from the transpilation process](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/issues/137#issue-208245680).

It seems difficult to publish an ES2015 package since this changes how clients consume the package. However people and tools start to figure out the [issues of this legacy inheritance](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/06/26/on-consuming-and-publishing-es2015+-packages), and search [new ways to tackle it](https://github.com/developit/microbundle/issues/304).

Comment: Have you had any problems, or is this a priori?

Comment: @serv-inc This is a priori. However, I would like to publish an es2015 version of an application that relies on several libraries. Some of these libraries are mine. All libraries are published in ES5. I am wondering if it is an issue to publish my libraries in ES2015...
Maybe I should edit the post to have a more problem-oriented question?